# Extracting up to $n$ elements after a specified marker from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a list from which I need to select up to two elements that follow each occurrence of a marker.

For example, the selected marker is `{"b","c"}` and the list is as follows:

```
  lis = {"a",{"b","c"},{"d","e"},{"f","g"},"h","i",{"b","c"},{"j","k"},{"l","m"},{"o"}}
```

This should give:

```
  res = {{{"d","e"},{"f","g"}},{{"j","k"},{"l","m"}}}
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: "Thank you Bill, lericr and Syed for the help! I will time some of these." I am honestly curious and I really do want to understand. What is it that makes people want the most efficient and the fastest possible and need to time this and ... people often make comments like that here, when they are using an interpreted rule based programming language that isn't really intended for speed? Is it because there isn't really anything else so might as well want the fastest possible speed? I'm not being rude, really, I just don't understand and would like to understand. Why is this? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SequenceCases[lis, {{"b", "c"}, a_, b_} :> {a, b}]
```

That assumes that you don't want a match if fewer than two items follow the {"b","c"}.

If that assumption is invalid, then maybe something like

```
SequenceCases[lis, {{"b", "c"}, follow__} :> Take[{follow}, UpTo[2]], Overlaps -> True]
```

Or even

```
SequenceCases[lis, {{"b", "c"}, follow___} :> Take[{follow}, UpTo[2]], Overlaps -> True]
```

Answer (score 6):

One way of doing that

```
Map[Take[lis,{#+1,#+2}]&,Flatten[Position[lis,{"b","c"}]]]
```

which returns

```
{{{d,e},{f,g}},{{j,k},{l,m}}}
```

and if you look at the `InputForm` of that you see it does include the quotes.

Please test that carefully on all the various kinds of input that you want to give it to make certain that you find any mistakes.

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[replaceMarkerWithNextKNeighborsInList]

replaceMarkerWithNextKNeighborsInList[list_, marker_, k_ : 2] := 
 Map[p |-> list[[p + 1 ;; UpTo[p + k]]]]@PositionIndex[list]@marker
```

***Examples:***

```
lis = {"a",{"b","c"},{"d","e"},{"f","g"},"h","i",{"b","c"}, 
       {"j","k"},{"l","m"},{"o"}};

replaceMarkerWithNextKNeighborsInList[lis, {"b", "c"}]
```

> ```
> {{{"d", "e"}, {"f", "g"}}, {{"j", "k"}, {"l", "m"}}}
> ```

```
replaceMarkerWithNextKNeighborsInList[lis, {"b", "c"}, 4]
```

> ```
> {{{"d", "e"}, {"f", "g"}, "h", "i"}, {{"j", "k"}, {"l", "m"}, {"o"}}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

With a slightly modified `lis` that may contain fewer items to pick after each of the markers:

```
lis = {"a", {"b", "c"}, {"d", "e"}, {"f", "g"}, "h", 
  "i", {"b", "c"}, {"j", "k"}, {"b", "c"}, {"l", "m"}, {"o"}}
```

**Using `Split`, `Take`:**

```
Split[lis, #2 != {"b", "c"} &] //
  Select[First@# == {"b", "c"} &] //
 Map[Take[#, {2, UpTo[3]}] & ]

{{{"d", "e"}, {"f", "g"}}, {{"j", "k"}}, {{"l", "m"}, {"o"}}}
```

Comment: Thank you Bill, lericr and Syed for the help!  I will time some of these.

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[kRightNeigbors]

kRightNeigbors[l_, k_ : 2] :=
   Map[p |-> l[[p + 1 ;; UpTo[p + k]]]] @* PositionIndex[l]
```

***Examples:***

```
kRightNeigbors[lis] @ {"b", "c"}
```

> ```
> {{{"d", "e"}, {"f", "g"}}, {{"j", "k"}, {"l", "m"}}}
> ```

```
Quiet @ Check[kRightNeigbors[lis] @ {"b", "d"}, {}]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

```
kRightNeigbors[lis, 4] @ {"b", "c"}
```

> ```
> {{{"d", "e"}, {"f", "g"}, "h", "i"}, {{"j", "k"}, {"l", "m"}, {"o"}}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative method using `Extract` and `Cases`:

```
Extract[#, Transpose@MapThread[Span @@@ {{#1 + 1, #2 - 1}, {#2 + 1, All}} &, 
Position[#, {"b", "c"}]]] &@Cases[lis, x_ /; Length[x] == 2]

(*{{{"d", "e"}, {"f", "g"}}, {{"j", "k"}, {"l", "m"}}}*)
```

Or using `SubsetCases`:

```
SubsetCases[lis, {{"b", "c"}, a_List, b_List} :> {a, b}]

(*{{{"d", "e"}, {"f", "g"}}, {{"j", "k"}, {"l", "m"}}}*)
```

Or using `Cases`:

```
Partition[Cases[#, x_ /; Length[x] == 2 && x =!= {"b", "c"}], Count[#, {"b", "c"}]] &@lis

(*{{{"d", "e"}, {"f", "g"}}, {{"j", "k"}, {"l", "m"}}}*)
```

Comment: The first one with `Extract` gives off a position error on my setup. Could you please verify?

Comment: Hi @Syed! In my configuration it does not generate any position error, and I just verified it.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iqS4.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjG5f.jpg

Comment: I will try to figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to you, mate!